# Meteor: return Promise's before responding to the HTTP post request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, promise, es6-promise

Within an endpoint defined using [Restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus) , I am calling AWS to return an object. I have simulated this function using a setTimeout function.

The purpose of async is of course not to block the server. However, I must wait for the `forEach` function to complete so the `newData` array can be returned to the client.

Currently, the end point returns immediately. How can I run the entire `forEach` function as one synchronous function. In other words, the endpoint will not return until the forEach function completes?

**server>download.js**

```
    class downloadClassed {
            constructor(){};

            downoadFile(key, ETag) {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                    resolve({key, ETag, status: "done"});
                            }, 1000 + Math.random() * 3000);
                    });
            }
    }

    downloadClass = downloadClassed;
```

**server>routes.js**

```
     // inside endpoint
    const cloudArray = [{ETag: 1, key: "a"}, {ETag: 2, key: "b"}, {ETag: 3, key: "c"}]

    let newData = [];

    cloudArray.forEach(function(cloudItem, index) {

            const downloadclass = new downloadClass();

            downloadclass.downoadFile(cloudItem.key, cloudItem.ETag)
            .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                   newData.push(data);
            })

    })

    console.log('return newData Array to client'); 
    return JSON.stringify(data: newData);
```

Comment: `Promise.all` does seem like an appropriate solution

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't exactly possible, but there's a way around it.

It's not possible because a function call is always synchronous, you can't make it "wait" for an async process to finish before returning. That's why we use callbacks, or other abstractions around them such as promises and event handlers.

When you want to do something after an asyncrhonous process ends, you register a callback. Or you use a promise, which is a mechanism that uses callbacks as its underlying implementation, but provides some advantages. Hence, you need to create a function that receives a callback or returns a promise.

In your case, you want to wait until *several* async processes finish (the downloads). `Promise.all` is very useful to do that. You can achieve it like this:

```
// You didn't include a signature, I made up a name for the function.
function downloadData() {
  const cloudArray = [{ETag: 1, key: "a"}, {ETag: 2, key: "b"}, {ETag: 3, key: "c"}]

  // cloudArray.map(fn) creates an array with the results of calling
  // fn on the values of cloudArray.
  const dataPromises = cloudArray.map(function (cloudItem, index) {
    const downloadclass = new downloadClass()
    // This returns a Promise so dataPromises will be an array of them.
    return downloadclass.downoadFile(cloudItem.key, cloudItem.ETag)
  })

  // Using Promise.all(dataPromises), we return a promise that's
  // fulfilled after all the download promises are...
  return Promise.all(dataPromises)
  .then((dataArray) => {
    // ...and resolves to a JSON string for this object
    return JSON.stringify({data: dataArray})
  })
}
```

The caller of your function will receive a Promise, which requires them to use `.then(someFunction)` to use the data, like so:

```
downloadData()
.then((data) => {
  console.log("look what I got from the internet!", data)
})
```

You may read [a gentle introduction to promises here](https://www.promisejs.org/). There are great libraries to handle promises and do idiomatic stuff (more value for less code). [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com), [q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) and [rsvp](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/) are some of them.

Comment: The rest endpoint returns before the Promise.all function completes. But the Promise.all is perfect in terms of capturing all the resolved data into an array.

Comment: Yes, like I said, the function **cannot** wait to return. It's simply not possible in the language. If the answer is not good enough to be accepted, please let me know what's missing to fix your problem and we can work it out.

Comment: I used the future library to wait on the response.

Comment: Please keep in mind that [future](https://www.npmjs.com/package/future) has not been actively maintained for a long time. As long as you understand that there's no real "wait" being done by the function, fine with me.